# problem a4j:poll and h:graphic image

Tags: richfaces

hello
I have a class that gives me an image in the server
image is changed periodically
the problem is that  the image is not is that refreshed  in my web page

---

```
        <a4j:region>
            <h:form>
                <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="500" enabled="true"
                    reRender="poll,out" />
            </h:form>
        </a4j:region>
        <h:form>            


 <a4j:outputPanel id="out">

 <h:graphicImage id="myp" rendered="#{simpleTask.running}"
                    url="/img/sample_loading.gif" style="height : 157px; width : 205px;"/>




                </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image is probably cached, you might want to change its URL.